# Facebook Phonegap xCode: Program Freaks Out When Returns From Authorization

Tags: facebook-graph-api, jquery-mobile, cordova

Here's what I want: Dialog box that says "Hey we gotta login to facebook and authorize" and then a button that goes to the facebook login page, then for it to return to a main page (the one that launched the dialog.

Right now, the dialog pops up fine, then it properly redirects to facebook, then redirects back but instead of just popping out to the main page, it pops out, then pops back up, then pops back out again. I'm sure I've done something I'm not supposed to. Also PLEASE comment on my jquery because I'm new to it and would rather not get into bad habits.

Here's what I have.

index.html which has this dialog box in the body:

```
<div id="dialog1" data-role="dialog" data-theme="b">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="inline">
                <h1> Welcome!</h1>          
            </div> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <p>
                <h5> Hey! Welcome to Tag Search. We need to take a few steps to set up the app. <br><br>
                    First you have to login to facebook and authorize Tag Search. Don't worry, we'll never post anything to your wall unless you tell us to! <br>
                </h5>
                </p>
                <a id="loginBtn" data-role="button">Click Here to Login!</a> 

            </div> 
        </div>

In my <script> tags I have this event listener:


    $("#loginBtn").bind("click",function(x){
    $('#dialog1').dialog('close');
    login();
    });
```

Also:

```
    function login() {
            FB.login(
                     function(response) {
                     console.log(response.session);
                     if (response.session) {
                        getLoginStatus();
                     //alert('logged in');
                     } else {
                     alert('not logged in');
                     }
                     },
                     { perms: "email, friends_photos, offline_access" }
                     );
        }
```

And:

```
    function getLoginStatus() {

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                              if (response.status == 'connected') {
                              //alert('Connected');
                              if(!session_access_token)
                                session_access_token=response.session.access_token;
                                getMe();
                                $("#loginout").text('Logout');
                              $("#loginout").bind('click', function(){logout()});
                                           } else {
                                $.mobile.changePage('#dialog1', 'pop');
                              }
                              console.log(response);
                              });
        }
```

getLoginStatus is called on  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {

Answer (score 0):

just guessing, but these should be good ways to start:

**A) multiple binds (easier)**
It could be you are binding to your button multiple times, so when you click on it, your functions fire multiple times.

To check just add a console.log to your click handler and see how often it fires when you click on the button.

You have to keep in mind how Jquery Mobile handles pages - the first page loaded is your "anchor-page" which should stay in the DOM as long as you are not rel="external"-linking to another page (which will then become your new anchor-page). All additional pages (including dialogs) are appended to the anchor-page DOM, when you load them. Your anchor page is just hidden, but is not gone, so it's easy to bind multiple times thinking "page is gone, need to bind again". Using Phonegap I think you have a single file with all pages contained, so this should also hold there.

**B) Too many hashchanges firing (tricky)**
Think of JQM transitions as two parallel processes, because a hashChange fires along with every transition. On forward transitions, the hashchange is blocked (check JQM *$.mobile.urlHistory.ignoreNextHashChange*), on backwards transitions it can pass and takes care of the reverse transition.

You would have to find out, which processes are triggered and blocked if your page is behaving strange. Console inside JQM in the _handleHashChange and click routing (search for "click routing " just before _handleHashChange) to see what happens.

My guess would be A)

Good luck and let me know if it works or if you have any more questons on both A) and B)

Comment: OK so, the first way wasn't the problem. I added a console.log to the click handler and it only fired once.  The second one was too complicated for me, for now. Right now I took it out of phonegap and I'm just doing everything in jquery until the whole program is done and then I'll port it over. Easier to debug that way. But I will come back and comment again when I need help! Thanks so much!